# Image Content-Type when outputting HTML tags leads to problems

Tags: php

I have the following code which works perfectly fine in my php file and generates a histogram image. However as soon as I add an html tags it wouldn't generate a histogram anymore but an empty image. It seems to me that the problem is in the first line `header("Content-type: image/jpeg");`. But how can i fix it?

```
<html>
    <?php
        // Send the PNG header information. Replace for JPEG or GIF or whatever
        header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

            // This array of values is just here for the example.
            $data = array('3400','2570','245','473','1000','3456','780');

            // Get the total value of columns we are going to plot
            $sum = array_sum($data);

            // Get the height and width of the final image
            $height = 255;
            $width = 320;

            $im = imagecreate($width,$height); // width , height px

            // Generate the image variables
            $white = imagecolorallocate($im,255,255,255); 
            $black = imagecolorallocate($im,0,0,0);   
            $red = imagecolorallocate($im,255,0,0);   


            imageline($im, 10, 5, 10, 230, $black);
            imageline($im, 10, 230, 300, 230, $black);

            // Now plot each column
            $x = 15;   
            $y = 230;   
            $x_width = 20;  
            $y_ht = 0; 

            for ($i=0;$i<7;$i++){

              $y_ht = ($data[$i]/$sum)* $height;    

                  // This part is just for 3D effect
              imagerectangle($im,$x,$y,$x+$x_width,($y-$y_ht),$red);
                  imagestring( $im,2,$x-1,$y+10,$data[$i],$black);

              $x += ($x_width+20);  

            }

            imagejpeg($im);

    ?> 
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Graph not showing properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129173/graph-not-showing-properly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the  tag in your PHP file as it's not HTML document.
Make sure there's no space before 
`<?php` 
open tag.

Call that file within and img tag like

`<img src="genrated.jpg.php" />`

Answer (score 4):

You need two scripts, one that generates html with a `<img src="...">` in it that refernces the php file that makes the image...  You can't have the image directly in the html.

Comment: Plus, header statements must be sent out before any html output, so if the header statement is correct, It would have to be before any html output.